# How to check if rar-file is passworded?

Tags: algorithm, rar

I have to check if a rar-archive has a password or not using Java.

I have a rar headers description (https://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm) but not understand how to read them.

P.S. Junrar libs not working with current rar 5 version.

Comment: I'd read and compare the first 8 bytes of two identical .rar archives, one password protected and one not. Should help figuring out the encryption flags.

Answer (score 0):

According to that document, the encryption header, if any, is the header immediately following the RAR signature. So to check whether the archive as a whole is encrypted, just find the RAR signature, examine the header after it, and see if the header type ID is that of an encryption header.

Similarly, if the archive as a whole is *not* encrypted, you can check the individual file headers to see if any of them include an encryption record.